# How to split parts of a string in a list based on predefined part of in the string

Tags: python, string

Plese help me with below question

`sample_list = ['Ironman.mdc.googlesuite.net', 'Hulk.nba.abc.googlekey.net',
    'Thor.web.gg.hh.googlestream.net', 'Antman.googled.net',
 'Loki.media.googlesuite.net','Captain.googlekey.net']`

I would want everything preceeding 'googlesuite.net', 'googlekey.net','googlestream.net' and 'googled.net' in list1 and corresponding prefixes in another list as:

`result_list1=['Ironman.mdc', 'Hulk.nba.abc', 'Thor.web.gg.hh', 'Antman',
 'Loki.media', 'Captain']`


`result_list2=['googlesuite.net', 'googlekey.net', 'googlestream.net', 'googled.net',
 'googlesuite.net', 'googlekey.net']`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a list comprehension along with `split`:

```
sample_list = ['Ironman.googlesuite.net', 'Hulk.googlekey.net',
    'Thor.googlestream.net', 'Antman.googled.net', 'Loki.googlesuite.net',
    'Captain.googlekey.net']
result_list1 = [i.split('.')[0] for i in sample_list]
print(result_list1)
```

This prints:

```
['Ironman', 'Hulk', 'Thor', 'Antman', 'Loki', 'Captain']
```

This strategy is to retain, for each input domain, just the component up to, but not including, the first dot separator.  For the second list, we can use `re.sub` here:

```
result_list2 = [re.sub(r'^[^.]+\.', '', i) for i in sample_list]
print(result_list2)
```

This prints:

```
['googlesuite.net', 'googlekey.net', 'googlestream.net', 'googled.net',
 'googlesuite.net', 'googlekey.net']
```

Comment: also `result_list2 = [''.join(i.split('.')[1:]) for i in sample_list]`

Comment: @JoranBeasley That saying is a warning intended for people who do not have a visceral feel for when regex is an appropriate tool to use.  For straightforward text manipulations, as is the case here, regex is very appropriate.

Comment: thank you for the answers, it does help but what if I have list like this:

`
sample_list = ['Ironman.mdc.googlesuite.net', 'Hulk.nba.googlekey.net',
    'Thor.web.googlestream.net', 'Antman.googled.net', 'Loki.googlesuite.net',
    'Captain.googlekey.net']

Comment: Why are you changing your question after many others have answered?

Answer (score 5):

You can always split each string in the list with '.' and get a new list. In this case, if you are only interested in the first split, you should use the second argument in the split method (which tells the occurrence):

```
first_list =[x.split('.')[0] for x in sample_list]
```

For the second list:

```
second_list =[x.split('.',1)[1] for x in sample_list]
```

A better way is to iterate only once through the sample_list and get both the lists. As shown below:

```
first_list, second_list = zip(* [x.split('.',1) for x in sample_list])
```

Answer (score 0):

thank you for the answers, it does help but what if I have list like this:

`sample_list = ['Ironman.mdc.googlesuite.net', 'Hulk.nba.abc.googlekey.net',
    'Thor.web.gg.hh.googlestream.net', 'Antman.googled.net', 'Loki.media.googlesuite.net','Captain.googlekey.net']`

I would want everything preceeding 'googlesuite.net', 'googlekey.net','googlestream.net' and 'googled.net'  in list1 and corresponding prefixes in another list as:

`result_list1=['Ironman.mdc', 'Hulk.nba.abc', 'Thor.web.gg.hh', 'Antman', 'Loki.media', 'Captain']`

`result_list2=['googlesuite.net', 'googlekey.net', 'googlestream.net', 'googled.net',
 'googlesuite.net', 'googlekey.net']`