# Extracting parts of a string preceeding a particular fixed text in the string

Tags: python, string, list

Plese help me with below question

```
sample_list = ['Ironman.mdc.googlesuite.net', 'Hulk.nba.abc.googlekey.net',
               'Thor.web.gg.hh.googlestream.net', 'Antman.googled.net',
               'Loki.media.googlesuite.net','Captain.googlekey.net']
```

I would want everything preceeding  'googlesuite.net', 'googlekey.net','googlestream.net' and 'googled.net' in list1 and corresponding prefixes in another list as:

```
result_list1 = ['Ironman.mdc', 'Hulk.nba.abc', 'Thor.web.gg.hh', 'Antman',
                'Loki.media', 'Captain']
result_list2 = ['googlesuite.net', 'googlekey.net', 'googlestream.net',
                'googled.net', 'googlesuite.net', 'googlekey.net']
```

Comment: This is exactly the same question you asked 1 hr ago. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60595247/how-to-split-parts-of-a-string-in-a-list-based-on-predefined-part-of-in-the-stri All you have to do is use `split(s,2)`

Comment: @Ch3steR can you please write it as a whole, would greatly appreciate